# Using dart's async with stack_trace's Chain

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to take advantage of the Chain object provided by stack_trace like so:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart';

main() async {
  print('Hello world: ${console_test.calculate()}!');
  Chain.capture(() async {
    try {
      await testFunction();
    } catch(e,st) {
      print(Trace.format(new Chain.forTrace(st)));
    }
  });
}


Future testFunction() async {
  throw new Exception("TEST");
}
```

The output I get is this:

```dart
Hello world: 42!
main.dart 4:1  main.<async>.<fn>.<async>
```

I understand that the outputted stack trace should include testFunction, but for some reason it isn't. If I do it with futures instead:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart';

main() async {
  print('Hello world: ${console_test.calculate()}!');
  Chain.capture(()  {
      return testFunction();
  }, onError: (e, stackTrace) => print(Trace.format(new Chain.forTrace(stackTrace))));
}

Future testFunction() async {
  throw new Exception("TEST");
}
```

I get more expected output:

```dart
Hello world: 42!
main.dart 17:3       testFunction.<async>
dart:async           _Completer.completeError
main.dart 4:1        testFunction.<async>
dart:async           Future.Future
main.dart 4:1        testFunction
main.dart 11:26      main.<async>.<fn>
package:stack_trace  Chain.capture
main.dart 10:16      main.<async>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is Chain incompatible with the whole async/await thing?

Answer (score 3):

What versions of Dart and `stack_trace` are you using? On Dart `1.9.0-edge.44028` with `stack_trace` `1.2.3`, after deleting the `console_test` line, I get the following output:

```
test.dart 16:3       testFunction.<async>
dart:async           _Completer.completeError
test.dart 17:2       testFunction.<async>
dart:async           Future.Future.microtask
test.dart 7:25       main.<async>.<fn>.<async>
package:stack_trace  Chain.capture
test.dart 5:16       main.<async>
```

It's also worth noting that you don't really need to use `Trace.format` with `Chain`. You can just use `Chain.terse`, which will also preserve the asynchronous gaps.

Comment: I'm on 1.8.5 stable with stack_trace 1.2.3.

Comment: I'm using Trace.format to convert it to a string. Chain.terse doesn't do that.

Comment: Just tried it again with the 1.9.0 dev build, and it works properly. I did find a workaround though, and I'm going to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@nex3 correctly pointed out that my original example in fact works in the 1.9.0 dev build of Dart, so this might just be an incompatibility at present. Regardless, taking the async off of the Chain.capture, changing the await on testFunction() to a return and using an await on Chain.Capture actually produce the correct output. This obviously isn't 100% optimal, but it gets the job done.

```dart
main() async {
  print('Hello world: ${console_test.calculate()}!');
  var test = await Chain.capture(() {
    return testFunction();
  },
  onError: (e, stackTrace) => print(Trace.format(new Chain.forTrace(stackTrace))));
  print(test);
}

Future testFunction() async {
  return "nice!";
  throw new Exception("TEST");
}
```